# Loading html page's body into another page without ajax

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a page which has footer and some common parts.

On click of any link in footer the body tag should be loaded with the content of another markup file. This is very simple on server side, but the all html pages will be residing on a client device, ant the way to access other files is to use file protocol. So, ajax is out of the question as well.

There is jsonp, but the content will be in pure markup and not in JSON. Also there will be issues with html tags in JSON if I decide to assign one element with entire content.

Is there any other way to achieve this using plain JS?

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest using FRAMEs - if they are supported by device browser.

Comment: "...file protocol..." - No it's not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just perfectly described frames. Is there any reason you aren't using them (other than "frames are bad, mkay?").

Answer (score 0):

[Framesets](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp) allow you to divide the page in sections and links can target **one** given section.

If you need to target a particular frame that is of known height and width and doesn't fit the structure of framesets, you can use iframes and change its src attribute with javascript.

```
<iframe id="myframe" height="400" width="500" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementByID('myframe').src = 'somelocalfile.html';
</script>
```

Using any of these strategies you will have to solve the problem of scrollbars. You could use javascript to determine the child page content height and adjust the iframe height from the parent page.